# When to use static or dynamic assests in Vue + webpack

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I am developing a webpage in Vue, and I see there are two ways of addressing and saving images or css files. Either through a relative path or from the static folder.

The question is, what is the difference? When should i give preference to one method or the other? Are there performance issues?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the difference?

when you use **relative paths**, the files are resolved and handled by webpack.

For example in `<template>` tag you use a relative path to address an image as follows:

```
<template>
<div>
    <img src="./images/cat.png" alt="cat">
</div>
</template>
```

will be converted into a module dependency as:

```
createElement('img', {
attrs: {
    src: require('../images/cat.png') // this is now a module depency
}
})
```

In the above example the file being handled is an image file with .png extension. So for webpack to know that the required object is as file and to return its public URL vue cli uses [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) and [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) out of the box.

Bu when handling assets from the **static** directory the files are not processed by webpack and copied as is. You need to use **absolute paths** to reference the file. For example `/static/cat.png`

> Are there performance issues?

when you use relative paths the files are handled by `url-loader`. You can find it in build/webpack.base.conf.js file as follows:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  }
```

the `limit` option mentioned above tells the url loader to inline the file as a base 64 string. For example if you have

```
//main.js
const cat = require(../images/cat.png); // cat.png is less than 10000 bytes
```

it will be converted and inlined into the main.js file instead of copy the image file into the dist folder as:

```
//main.js
const cat = url("data:image/png;base64,iVBFfaGVVGfF...);
```

If it is a trivial file and smaller than 10000 bytes the browser doesn't have to query the server for the image data separately, saving a round trip thus reducing the number of requests to the server.

But if the file size is greter than 10000 kb url-loader will automatically hand the job to file-loader.

file-loader allows you to configure where to copy the file and how to name it.

> When should i give preference to one method or the other

when you  dont want webpack to handle your assets, use **static** folder. But keep in mind to use absolute paths.

Just use relative paths and leave the hassle to webpack whether to inline or use file-loader to copy/rename the file using [version hashes](https://codeburst.io/long-term-caching-of-static-assets-with-webpack-1ecb139adb95?gi=9e32667ae5c5#.vtwnssps4) which is better for caching .

For more refere to :

- [Handling static assets](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html)
- [Vue-loader Asset URL Handlung](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html)