# Nuxt.js: Include font files: use /static or /assets

Tags: vue.js, fonts, font-face, assets, nuxt.js

I know some posts in the nuxt.js github repo cover this a bit, but I would like to know what is the correct way to use font-files in nuxt.js.

So far we had them in the `/static/fonts` directory, but other people use `assets` to store the font files.
What are the differences? Is one of the options better and if so, why?

Also there are different ways to include them.
Would a path like this be correct:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontName';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('~static/fonts/font.file.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Mode */
  src: url('~static/fonts/font.file.woff') format('woff'),
       url('~static/fonts/font.file.otf') format('otf'),
       url('~static/fonts/font.file.eot') format('eot');
}
```

Thanks for some clarification here :D.
cheers

J

Comment: hey check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50062023/7814783). I think its a bit related

Answer (score 19, accepted):

it's very well explained on the official doc: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/

`assets\` is reserved for assets to be processed (eg. concat css with webpack)

`static\` is useful to expose all static files from the root url  (static\img\test.jpg => http://example.fr/img/test.jpg), without any process

Comment: Ok. I somehow did not find this. Thanks for the clarification. Cheers

Comment: The docs don't answer the question. Which is better for fonts? If you're loading Google fonts, should you load them from the CDN, and if so, where in the app do you do it?

Comment: @ccleve to import a resource (eg. a font) from a CDN, the better way si to declare it in your "nuxt.config.js" file as explained in docs: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/#global-settings

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets#fonts

Comment: actually the docs say initially that assets is the directory for images, sass-files and for *fonts*, but then they also state that you can also use the static folder.
I would assume that by the nature of font files, you don't want to touch them or processed by webpack and therefore `static` would be the better place to store them?
Or am I missing something?